# Getting javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader error on Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
```

I'm using IntelliJ 2019.3 Ultimate (not Maven).

- I saw an article that `getClassLoader()` method is provided since servlet-api version 2.5. I thought proper library was not included. So I tried to add library which is included in Tomcat 8.5.57.
- I thought the servlet-api.jar in IntelliJ overrides the servlet-api.jar in Tomcat folder, so I deleted it.
- I thought maybe it's because I didn't include the javax.servlet.ServletContext. So I wrote it on the code; still not working.

When I create the project I checked Web Application and WebServices beneath that Web Application option (version 4.0). And I added Tomcat 8.5.57 at run -> edit configuration. On my desktop I did same thing (added lib folder in Tomcat) but it perfectly worked.

Since I'm getting same error whatever I do, I think proper version of servlet-api.jar is not included or being overrided by older version of servlet-api.jar. Is it because I installed IntelliJ on D drive?

Comment: Is it possible to share your project?